# Android: BitmapFactory.decodeResource returning null

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, android-context

I can't seem to figure this out. I have 2 java classes with different characteristics, each calling BitmapFactory.decodeResource to get the same image resource, one returns the bitmap while the other returns null. Both classes are in the same package.

Here is the class that works, it calls BitmapFactory.decodeResource which returns the bitmap. I've only included relevant code.

```
package advoworks.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MainScreen extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static final String TAG = MainScreen.class.getSimpleName();

    public MainScreen(Context context) {
        super(context);

        Bitmap bitmap;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.droid_1);

        //adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events;
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
        setFocusable(true);

    }
}
```

Here is the class that doesn't work.  BitmapFactory.decodeResource returns a NULL in debug. I've only included code i felt was relevant.

```
package advoworks.test;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;

public class Segment {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public Segment(int x, int y) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating Segment");
        try {
            this.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.droid_1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Error is " + e);
        }   
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        Log.d(TAG, "Created Segment");
    }
}
```

Any clue anyone?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the logcat?

Comment: no i'm not getting any errors in logcat :(

Comment: Why do u need to load the same resource twice in the same app. Load it once and pass its reference to all places u need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getResources()` is a `Context` class method and you are not using a context in your Segment class. How does it work. You should call `getApplicationContext().getResources()`

You should pass the context to the `Segment` constructor.

```
public Segment(Context context, int x, int y) {
    ....
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.droid_1);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you explain what you mean by a "Context class method"? I can't find a definition on google.

Comment: `getResources()` is a member of the `Context` class. So context object is needed to call that method.

Comment: why doesn't getResources result in a compile error then?
Anyway I've tried doing this:

Comment: Anyway I've tried to get a "Context" like this by extending the class Application:

`public class Segment extends Application {`<br/>
    `public Segment(int x, int y) {`<br/>
        `try {`<br/>
            `Context context;`<br/>
            `context = getApplicationContext();`<br/>
            `this.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.droid_1);`<br/>
    `} catch (Exception e) {`<br/>
        `Log.d(TAG,"Error is " + e);`<br/>
    `}`
`}`

Comment: Sorry not used to using the mini markdowns

The code fails at context = getApplicationContext();
The error returned is java.lang.NullPointerException
What is the best way to get the context?

Comment: Where do you use your segment class? Do you have a context there? I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Check the resolution of your image, if its too big, the BitmapFactory.decodeResource will just return null (no exception)

Answer (score 3):

make sure your image is not in **drawable-v24** folder, move it to **drawable** folder.

this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem as well

Answer (score -2):

My solution is to create a drawable (I had no issues creating it), then convert it to a bitmap

```
val drawable = context.getDrawable(context.resources, R.drawable.droid_1)
val bitmap = drawable.toBitmap(width = 100, height = 100, config = null)
```

You can also use `drawable.width` and `drawable.height` to have the same scale and resolution